# Hope it gets better if he's trying to run whatever it is off

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> He moving better than before but still doesn't seem he can sprint. Hope it gets better if he's trying to run whatever it is off. –

what does it mean (to run whatever it is off) in that sentence.

Comment: He moving better than before but still doesn't seem he can sprint.  Hope it gets better if he's trying to run whatever it is off.

Comment: Please tell us where you read or heard this. What was the context? Who said it about whom, and to whom? If you can link to the source that is best.  You can [edit] your own question so you don't need to add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess in the context would be that “it” might be referring to an injury or cramp.

The speaker or writer doesn’t know the cause but has noticed that the person isn’t able to run at full speed, but is improving. To “run it off” can be used when talking about running through a muscle cramp until it passes or a similar pain/minor injury.

It is hard to tell in more detail without more context.

Comment: but verb to be (is) *to run whatever it ^is^ off*.